# How to calculate the total of all the number between 1 and the number that the user entered?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have to ask the user to enter an integer number and the program will calculate the total of all the number between 1 and the number that the user entered. For example, if I enter `5` and the output will be `The total is 15`

Comment: Why the tag "pycharm"? Is it your homework? What it is the problem? [and a small trick, do you know the formula to calculate the sum of all integer between two numbers? But probably the assignment do not want that you use such well know formula)

Comment: As you question reads as "do my homework for me" you will probably be downvoted and not get any answers. Is there anything specific that you need problem with, such as "getting the input from the users", "loop over the numbers", "add numbers", "output the result" or "isn't there a more effective formula for this"?

Comment: I tagged pycharm because I have to write the code in pycharm. It is my homework that is left in the past, I want to complete it even though I don't get much from it. Calculate the all the numbers between 1 and the number user entered. I don't know the small trick. The assignment don't say anything about it

Comment: Sorry, I wanted ask for the most effective formula/code to be able to do this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take the user input. assign total = 0 and then loop

```
   num = int(input("Enter number: "))

    tot = 0

    for i in range(num + 1):
        tot += i

    print(tot)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is just simply the following:

```
def func(userVal):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, userVal):
        sum += i
    print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a non loop approach:

See it as

1+2+3+4+5

Add first and last (1+5) = 6

Add second and second last (2+4) = 6

Add remaining 3

In other words:
(input+1) = 6

times

(input/2) = 2.5

(**2** * input = **2*6**) + (**0.5** * input = **3**)
= 2*6 + 3

Or in short:

`result = (input+1) * input/2;`

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  var input = parseInt($('#input').val());
  var result = (input+1) * input/2;
  
  $('#output').text(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Calculate">
<br />
Result: <span id="output"></span>
```